# Keep only elements of a list which contain a string in another vector (R)

Tags: r, regex, string, list, find

I have a vector of string keywords, and a list containing many elements with strings. I would like to keep the elements of the list that contain at least one string from the vector.

I have tried filtering with dplyr, %in%, etc.

Here is an example:

```
words <- c("find", "these", "words")

paragraph <- list(text1 = c("these", "words", "are", "helpful"),
              text2 = c("nothing", "to", "see", "here"),
              text3 = c("we", "can", "find", "one", "here"))
```

I would like to end up with a list including just text1 and text3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `Filter` from `base R`. Create a logical `vector` with `%in%` an wrap with `any`

```
Filter(function(x) any(words %in% x), paragraph)
#$text1
#[1] "these"   "words"   "are"     "helpful"

#$text3
#[1] "we"   "can"  "find" "one"  "here"
```

---

Or using `sapply`

```
paragraph[sapply(paragraph, function(x) any(words %in% x))]
```

Or using `lengths` and `intersect`

```
paragraph[lengths(Map(intersect, list(words), paragraph)) > 0]
```

---

or with `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
keep(paragraph, ~ any(words %in% .x))
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much, the last option worked like a charm. Much appreciated :)